# Cannot boot LiveCD of Ubuntu GNOME 16.10

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, nomodeset

After having issues with a black screen (`nomodeset` resolved this) now the system gets stuck on booting. I tried to boot without `splash` and `quiet`. It boots normally to some point and then simply stops (the console also flickers for some time). I tried `nomodeset` in my VM where it boots without this and now I'm having the same issue there as on my real machine. If I remove `nomodeset` it boots up normally.
[Here's a screenshot from my VM hanging on boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bX1y.png)

In my VM it occures with EFI enabled and disabled.

Comment: I suspect that X (the Ubuntu GUI) is not starting. What type of video device do you have? (ATI/AMD? Intel? Nvidia? Something more exotic?) Did you install a third-party video driver (these are available for ATI/AMD and Nvidia, but not for Intel, AFAIK)? Sometimes a third-party driver helps and other times it hurts.

Comment: @RodSmith As the title says I'm trying to start the LiveCD. The same occurs when trying to boot the installation of Ubuntu GNOME. I have an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970.